# Is it safe to use my US iPhone/iPad charger with a simple European plug adapter?

Tags: ipad, iphone, power, charging

I'm using the US wall adapter that came with my iPhone to charge it:
[image]

When I travel to Europe, is it safe to use this with a simple US-European adapter, or do I need a transformer or some other device to step to the appropriate voltage/current? Do I risk frying my device?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the simple adapter.  If you read the tiny fine print on the plug end you see "110-240V 50-60Hz" which means it will work on most common electrical systems around the world without a transformer.

Comment: You'll find that most new apple equipment, chargers, and power bricks are all labeled for 110-240V, 50-60Hz AC power.

Comment: it's been true of Apple chargers for at least 7 years.  My original PPC iBook was from the USA and all I needed was the UK adaptor for the charger.

Comment: Europe had voltages ranging from 220 (NL) to 240 (UK) and is in the process of transforming that into a Europe wide 230V 50Hz. The only exception I could find at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country - Okt 2014 - is Norway at 240 Volts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to use a simple adapter for EU. You do not need additional transformers. When I went in visit to Europe I got one adapter exactly like the one in your post, the black one.